# How to show Islamic (Hijri) calendar in datePickerDialog in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-calendar, android-datepicker, hijri

I am using below code but this is showing up the gregorian calendar instead of Hijri Calendar...

```
val locale = ULocale("@calendar=islamic-umalqura")
val calendar = android.icu.util.Calendar.getInstance(locale) 
////tried IslamiCalendar.getInstance(locale) but not working
val date = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{
        view: DatePicker?, year: Int, month: Int, dayOfMonth: Int ->
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.YEAR] = year
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.MONTH] = month
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH] = dayOfMonth
    }
    val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
        LocalContext.current,
        date,
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.YEAR],
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.MONTH],
        calendar[android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
    ).show()
```

Comment: I think you have to either create your own date picker, or use a third party library like this: https://github.com/alhazmy13/HijriDatePicker

Comment: I'm using jetpack compose and this 3rd party lib hijriDatepicker doesn't support compose.

Comment: You can mix and match. A DatePickerDialog doesn’t use Compose anyway. Since it’s a self-contained dialog, it especially doesn’t matter if it uses Compose like the rest of your app.